# Does the watchOS version of the Voice Memos app enforce a time limit for audio recordings?

Tags: apple-watch, voice-memo

As of watchOS 6, the Voice Memos app is now included allowing for on-the-wrist recording of audio content. Is there a hard-limit on the total duration of recordings made directly on the Apple Watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Charge up your battery and fill your storage space.